# Unable to update ngrx store to version 9

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

Trying to upgrade to ngrx/store v9 but I receive a list of dependencies that need to be fixed. I have fixed all of them but the only one remaining is the following:

```
Package "@angular-devkit/build-angular" has an incompatible peer dependency to "typescript" (requires ">=3.1 < 3.6", would install "3.8.3").
```

I cannot find a solution to this one as my typescript is already at version 3.5.1 which falls in the adequate range, yet it still requires me to update it. What is the issue here?

This is part of a bigger update to get the version of Angular from 7 to 10, stating this just in case it offers some info.

SOLUTION:

Increase @angular-devkit/build-angular to a higher version. For my case: 0.901.3 worked

Comment: use the --force switch

Comment: Is there a way to work around this?